# Docker volume data gets stored twice?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am using a mysql docker image through docker-compose and I get its data stored twice (on the host and in docker data folder).
What I want is to have one copy of mysql data stored on the "host".
I've read through the docker and docker-compose docs and I don't seem to get how this is supposed to be working.

Here is the docker-compose config I am using:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: "mysql"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      device: /local/path
      o: bind
```

When I inspect the disk contents I can see that the mysql data is stored twice:

- inside the docker data folder, e.g. `/var/lib/docker/volumes/myapp_mysql-data/_data`
- on the "host" at `/local/path`

Is this "normal"? What do people use to have mysql in docker but its data located somewhere else?

Updated:
Here is the output of the `docker volume inspect myapp_mysql-data`:

```
docker volume inspect myapp_mysql-data
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "...",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "myapp",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.0",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "mysql-data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myapp_mysql-data/_data",
        "Name": "myapp_mysql-data",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/local/path",
            "o": "bind"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Comment: if you look at `mount` output are they both `bind`ed to the same location?

Comment: added output of volume inspect

Comment: `mount | grep mysql-data` as a linux command - what does that show?

Comment: Oh, I see. `findmnt -n -o SOURCE --target /local/path   -->   /dev/vda1` `findmnt -n -o SOURCE --target /var/lib/docker/volumes/myapp_mysql-data/_data   -->  /dev/vda1[/local/path]`. The confusion I am having is because I moved /var/lib/docker to another digital ocean "drive" (under `/mnt/...`) and when I run `ncdu` it showed disk usage as if I have two copies of the data on my local path and on `/mnt/...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like it works as expected, i.e. docker has volume's `_data` folder binded to the same location as `local path`. Thanks @danblack!

The reason for my confusion was `ncdu` tool that I used to see what takes space on disks, which (after I moved the docker data folder to another disk) showed both folders as if they take the same amount of space.